# storyboard is displayed differently on simulator ipad in swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, storyboard, ios-simulator, xcode11.4

I have an app that was previously made for iPhone before, so i recently added an iPad storyboard, i followed some of the answers to related questions guidelines e.g

```
targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"and change it to targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
```

i also added the ipad storyboard to my info menu

[image]

The only thing i have not yet done is this since i use Xcode 11.5, i couldn't see it in my storyboard source code

```
<simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" type="retina4"/> and change it to to <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
```

This is how my app is displayed on the simulator

[image]

versus how it looks on my storyboard below. Please don't mind the labels because they are localized in the simulator. Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

[image]